# InvoiceAddGroup QuickBooks SDK Incorrect Price

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

I wrote a program that downloads orders from a website and creates invoices using the SDK.
A few products are listed as Groups in QuickBooks, so when adding them to the invoice, I can't list the price.

```
If IList.Item(x).Type = 2 Then
                Dim ORInvoiceLineAddListElement2 As IORInvoiceLineAdd
                ORInvoiceLineAddListElement2 = newInvoice.ORInvoiceLineAddList.Append()
                ORInvoiceLineAddListElement2.InvoiceLineGroupAdd.ItemGroupRef.FullName.SetValue(IList.Item(x).FullName)
                ORInvoiceLineAddListElement2.InvoiceLineGroupAdd.Quantity.SetValue(IList.Item(x).Quantity)
                'ORInvoiceLineAddListElement2.InvoiceLineGroupAdd.Desc.SetValue(IList.Item(x).DESC)
            End If
```

This will input into QuickBooks just fine, however, the price will be based on a retail customer, even if the customer class is set to wholesale.  I know that the customer class is correct because everything else shows up correctly in the generated invoice.

Any suggestions on what i could try to get this group item priced correctly?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks `Class` codes have nothing at all to do with pricing. They have no effect what-so-ever on pricing in any form or manner.

What makes you think setting the `Class` should change pricing in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. what is happening is the Group line items are being assigned the Default Price from the Items table. shouldn't have anything to do with the Class. I did find the following support answer which seems to apply to both Desktop and Online versions of QuickBooks:

"The SDK does not currently support adjusting the price of group items when adding an invoice, even though the default UI in QuickBooks allows this. You can modify an invoice and change the line item amounts, so you would need to first call create the add, read the response to get the transaction id and edit sequence, then do an Invoice Mod request on the invoice to set the rates that you want."

[Intuit Developer Page](https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1179246-how-can-i-add-price-attributes-to-an-invoice-with-item-groups)